# Can I use MANCOVA and SEM?

Tags: experiment-design, structural-equation-modeling, ancova, control-group

My project model includes one input variable, two mediators (both measured at the individual level, but one is about the team so rWG will be calculated), one moderator, and two outcome variables (again, both measured at the individual level, but one is about the team so rWG will be calculated). **It will be a pre-post design with experimental and control groups**. I plan on the following data analysis in the order of **CFA, Structural model (mediation and moderation analysis), and MANCOVA for the group differences**. Is the process redundant? How do I better my analysis strategy?